# Why this oracle query saying 'Single row subquery returns more than one row'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am writing sql query in oracle. my requirement is i want to update database column conditionally with case. Below is the sample data that i have been using with three tables.

```
create table z_product(uuid int, variationvalue varchar(10));
create table z_listprice(productid int, price int);
create table z_variation(masterproductid int, productid int);

insert into z_product values(1,null);
insert into z_product values(2,null);
insert into z_product values(3,null);
insert into z_product values(4,null);
insert into z_product values(5,null);
insert into z_product values(6,null);

insert into z_listprice values(1,10);
insert into z_listprice values(3,20);
insert into z_listprice values(5,10);
insert into z_listprice values(6,19);

insert into z_variation values(2, 1);
insert into z_variation values(2, 3);
insert into z_variation values(4, 5);
insert into z_variation values(4, 6);
```

i want to update the 'variationvalue' column if the all price values are equal for 'masterproductid'  with 'eqaul' if prices are different with 'notequal' message.

Query that i tried is

```
UPDATE z_product pr SET pr.variationvalue =
        CASE WHEN ( SELECT numberofrows FROM (SELECT COUNT(*)  AS numberofrows, pricecount , productmasterid
                              FROM ( SELECT COUNT(prl.price) AS pricecount , prl.price AS price, prv.masterproductid AS productmasterid
                                        FROM  z_variation prv, z_listprice prl
                                        WHERE prv.masterproductid = (SELECT prv.masterproductid
                                                                        FROM z_variation prv
                                                                        WHERE prv.productid = prl.productid GROUP BY prv.masterproductid)
                                        AND prl.productid = prv.productid
                                        GROUP BY prl.price, prv.masterproductid)
                    GROUP BY pricecount , productmasterid)) = '1'
                    AND 
                    ( SELECT pricecount FROM (SELECT COUNT(*)  AS numberofrows, pricecount , productmasterid
                              FROM ( SELECT COUNT(prl.price) AS pricecount , prl.price AS price, prv.masterproductid AS productmasterid
                                        FROM  z_variation prv, z_listprice prl
                                        WHERE prv.masterproductid = (SELECT prv.masterproductid
                                                                        FROM z_variation prv
                                                                        WHERE prv.productid = prl.productid GROUP BY prv.masterproductid)
                                        AND prl.productid = prv.productid
                                        GROUP BY prl.price, prv.masterproductid)
                    GROUP BY pricecount , productmasterid)) >1
        THEN 'equal'
        ELSE 'notequal' END
WHERE pr.uuid = (SELECT prv.masterproductid
                    FROM z_variation prv, z_listprice prl
                    WHERE prv.productid = prl.productid 
                    AND pr.uuid = prv.masterproductid GROUP BY prv.masterproductid)
```

what is wrong with this query. where i am doing wrong. Any suggestions will be greatly appriciated

Comment: @bernie i am new to sql please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Apologies, my comment was in poor taste. I have removed it.

Comment: The error message means that one or more of your subqueries is returning more than one value so Oracle doesn't know which one to use.

Comment: @ bernie i tested all sub queries which are working with out error but putting together causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more investigating and it looks like you're returning multiple PRODUCTMASTERIDs, thus returning 2 results -- See this Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da309/8

The results look like such:

```
NUMBEROFROWS PRICECOUNT PRODUCTMASTERID
2            1           4
2            1           2
```

Those subqueries should only return a single row to use with the CASE statement.  And since you're only checking the first column, adding DISTINCT works.  However, if NUMBEROFROWS were different values, then DISTINCT wouldn't work by itself.

```
UPDATE z_product pr SET pr.variationvalue =
        CASE WHEN ( SELECT DISTINCT numberofrows FROM (SELECT COUNT(*)  AS numberofrows, pricecount , productmasterid
                              FROM ( SELECT COUNT(prl.price) AS pricecount , prl.price AS price, prv.masterproductid AS productmasterid
                                        FROM  z_variation prv, z_listprice prl
                                        WHERE prv.masterproductid = (SELECT prv.masterproductid
                                                                        FROM z_variation prv
                                                                        WHERE prv.productid = prl.productid GROUP BY prv.masterproductid)
                                        AND prl.productid = prv.productid
                                        GROUP BY prl.price, prv.masterproductid)
                    GROUP BY pricecount , productmasterid)) = '1'
                    AND 
                    ( SELECT DISTINCT pricecount FROM (SELECT COUNT(*)  AS numberofrows, pricecount , productmasterid
                              FROM ( SELECT COUNT(prl.price) AS pricecount , prl.price AS price, prv.masterproductid AS productmasterid
                                        FROM  z_variation prv, z_listprice prl
                                        WHERE prv.masterproductid = (SELECT prv.masterproductid
                                                                        FROM z_variation prv
                                                                        WHERE prv.productid = prl.productid GROUP BY prv.masterproductid)
                                        AND prl.productid = prv.productid
                                        GROUP BY prl.price, prv.masterproductid)
                    GROUP BY pricecount , productmasterid)) >1
        THEN 'equal'
        ELSE 'notequal' END
WHERE pr.uuid = (SELECT prv.masterproductid
                    FROM z_variation prv, z_listprice prl
                    WHERE prv.productid = prl.productid 
                    AND pr.uuid = prv.masterproductid GROUP BY prv.masterproductid)
```

**--EDIT--**

If I'm understanding your requirements correctly -- that is, for any given masterproductid, if any prices are different in the listprice table, then you want to update the variationvalue to notequal, but if the prices are the same, then you want to udpate the column to equal, then try this:

```
MERGE
INTO    z_product
USING   (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT l.price) cnt,
          v.masterproductid
        FROM z_variation v
          JOIN z_listprice l on v.productid = l.productid
        GROUP BY v.masterproductid
        )
ON      (uuid = masterproductid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     variationvalue = CASE WHEN cnt = 1 THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not Equal' END
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/098ad/1

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much for your kind reply. I need to check for all masterproductids whether its variant price is same or not, if same i have to update 'variantvalue' column in product table with related messge. How this can be done ? thank you

Comment: @user964147 -- unfortunately I have to run for about 20 minutes -- be happy to help when I return.

Comment: @user964147 -- what are your desired results for each record in the z_product table -- that would help a lot.

Comment: @ sgeddes thank you very much for getting me back, i got the solution , i was missing where condition for subselect

Comment: @ sgeddes thanks, may be you can have a look at the answer that i posted below & suggestions are appreciated for better performance

Comment: @user964147 -- see edits above -- if my understanding of your issue is correct, then this should be a lot easier for you.  Best regards.

Comment: @user964147 -- no worries -- a little easier to read.  Just wanted to make sure my understanding was correct.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
UPDATE z_product pr SET pr.variationvalue =
        CASE WHEN ( SELECT numberofrows FROM (SELECT COUNT(*)  AS numberofrows, pricecount , productmasterid
                              FROM ( SELECT COUNT(prl.price) AS pricecount , prl.price AS price, prv.masterproductid AS productmasterid
                                        FROM  z_variation prv, z_listprice prl
                                        WHERE prv.masterproductid = (SELECT prv.masterproductid
                                                                        FROM z_variation prv
                                                                        WHERE prv.productid = prl.productid GROUP BY prv.masterproductid)
                                        AND prl.productid = prv.productid
                                        GROUP BY prl.price, prv.masterproductid)
                    GROUP BY pricecount , productmasterid) WHERE pr.uuid = productmasterid) = '1'
                    AND 
                    ( SELECT pricecount FROM (SELECT COUNT(*)  AS numberofrows, pricecount , productmasterid
                              FROM ( SELECT COUNT(prl.price) AS pricecount , prl.price AS price, prv.masterproductid AS productmasterid
                                        FROM  z_variation prv, z_listprice prl
                                        WHERE prv.masterproductid = (SELECT prv.masterproductid
                                                                        FROM z_variation prv
                                                                        WHERE prv.productid = prl.productid GROUP BY prv.masterproductid)
                                        AND prl.productid = prv.productid
                                        GROUP BY prl.price, prv.masterproductid)
                    GROUP BY pricecount , productmasterid) WHERE pr.uuid = productmasterid) >1
        THEN 'equal'
        ELSE 'notequal' END
WHERE pr.uuid = (SELECT prv.masterproductid
                    FROM z_variation prv, z_listprice prl
                    WHERE prv.productid = prl.productid 
                    AND pr.uuid = prv.masterproductid GROUP BY prv.masterproductid)
```